# How to run a powershell script in runonce-Key?

Tags: powershell, windows-7, runonce

I have a call to powershell.exe that looks like this, and which works from my commandline:

```
powershell.exe -noexit -command " & 'C:\Test\test.ps1' "
```

However, when I enter that entry exactly that way in the runonce-key of my current user, nothing happens.

What is the correct way to call powershell.exe passing parameters from runonce or run?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try with full path:

```
c:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noexit "C:\Test\test.ps1"
```

or

```
c:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noexit -command " & 'C:\Test\test.ps1' "
```

Comment: Thanks, it was an issue with the path, it works in commandshell because I guess the powershell-path is in my environment settings when already logged on, but not yet when the runonce-key is executed. However, I made the path a bit more universal: %WINDIR%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe, and use ExpandEnvironmentStrings before adding that path from another powershell-script to the registry. Will this also work for Win7 x64?

Comment: And what if you want to change the working directory of the script?

Answer (score 2):

A slightly different approach would be to put all your call to powershell.exe with all arguments / parameters into a simple *.bat file, and call that *.bat file from your RunOnce Key. This way you don't need to play around with params, which can mess-up sometimes. Your PowerShell script could even delete that *.bat file, since it is required only once.

Answer (score 1):

Use the File argument instead of command.
You can also use some of the other parameters to clean things up *(noprofile, sta, and/or WindowStyle)*

This is an example of what I use.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noprofile -sta -WindowStyle Hidden -File "C:\Test\Test.ps1"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it in a `cmd`. That way it has access to the normal `PATH` and can find powershell.

e.g.

```
cmd /c (powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -file "C:\Test\test.ps1")
```